# Increase a count if the number hits every 50 times

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I'm beginner, Please have a look below and need help.

`Count = 200`

When I run my program it will count from 1 to 200 and I need to increase the `pagekey` from 0 by 1 every time 50 hits. So the example I have the `pagekey` should go up to 4. Also I need to reset count back to 1 everytime the 50 hits. I have this code below but I can't figure it out.

I tried this below:

```
    int pagekey = 0;

    if (count > 49){
        pagekey =2;
        count = count - 49;
    }
```

How can i do this?

Comment: How would you ever reach 200 if you reset the count to 1 as soon as it reaches 50?

Comment: Do you want to add page after every 50 counts ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that i got this to work up to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int count = 1;
int pagekey = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
{
    count++;
    if (i% 50 == 0)
    {
        pagekey++;
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

If i / 50 has no remainder (i.e. is a multiple of 50) then do your "special cases".

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
    int pagekey = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && i % 50 == 0) {
            pagekey++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with a similar solution to John3136's solution

```
    int pageKey = 0;
    int count = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        count ++;
        if(i % 50 == 0) {
            pageKey += 1;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
```